# backbonejs validation on create

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js

this is my model

```
Msg = Backbone.Model.extend({
        validate: function(attr){
            if(attr.msg === undefined || attr.msg === ''){
                return "empty messege";
            }
        },
        initialize: function(){
            this.on('invalid',function(model,error){
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
});
```

and I have collection of Msgs msgCollection 
so if I do `msgCollection.create({msg:''});` 
this model gets added to collection 
how can I prevent this

Comment: That is not supposed to happen, from the docs: "If client-side validation failed, the model will be unsaved, with validation errors.". Only after the save, the model is added to the collection: "adding the model to the set after being successfully created".

Comment: @GijsjanB yes it does not fire post request but it is still  adding to collection on the client side

Comment: I have tested your code and in fact it does add the model (contrary to what the docs make you believe ;))! You can pass {wait: true} as an option, so it won't add or call collection.pop() from the invalid event listener. {wait:true} is the way to go, as the invalid event listener can be called also when you don't create a model and hence don't want to pop the last msg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record!

Pass

```
{wait:true}
```

as an option when you call create:

```
msgCollection.create({msg:''}, {wait:true});
```